# can we retrieve and deploy Single Sign-On setting using Ant

Tags: apex

i was trying to  retrieve and deploy Single Sign-On setting using Ant but i couldn't do it. please help me how to write package.xml for SSO

Answer (score 3):

This is the metadata type of SAML Single Sign On https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_samlssoconfig.htm

Here is a sample `package.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>SamlSsoConfig</name>
    </types>
    <version>50.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: The `SamlSsoConfig` metadata contains the external cert (`validationCert`), but the request signing cert -- in our case a self-signed cert -- is a hard-coded ID reference. So you can't deploy configs where the request signing cert has a different ID in the destination org. Basically, you can only deploy from sandboxes that were created from your destination org, so the destination cert will have a matching ID. Or, a find/replace for the ID if you have a DevOps tool/process that supports it.